# Cannot access the cshtml template in a 2sxc Mobius Forms app

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I want to make changes to the Simple Contact Form in the Mobius Forms 2sxc app, but I cannot find a way to do this in-line in the 2sxc app.  Has anyone tried to use the 2sxc dotnetnuke app?  It's an excellent dev tool, but has a learning curve...

I spent hours trying to figure this out, including watching all the videos available. Can't find one that shows editing  template for an existing 2sxc view of an app.

This seems like it should be an easy thing to figure out, but I cannot find the ability to edit in-line the .cshtml for the forms app (or any 2sxc app for that matter).

It's easy enough to in-line edit a 2sxc content, since there's a button to edit the template for that.  But for a 2sxc app, I can see which cshtml template I need to edit but cannot see a way to do that in the dnn application.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a host-user, you can rotate the ... button and get to a button which looks like `</>` - that's to edit the template online.

Otherwise you can always use any kind of editor (we like VS Code) and edit the files directly in the folder. ok?